# How to enable web support in XML configuration

Tags: spring, spring-data

I read the docs at http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#core.web and far as i understood this is how  i should enable web support in my xml configuration:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.data.web.config.SpringDataWebConfiguration" />
```

How ever if i do so I'm keep getting the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [org.project.User]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

I'm trying to get an id from an url like in the example in the docs.

I'm using `Spring 4.1.7.RELEASE` and the following dependency for `Spring Data`:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need the DomainClassConverter too:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.data.repository.support.DomainClassConverter">
  <constructor-arg ref="conversionService"/>
</bean>
```

You might also need:

```
<bean 
 class="org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean" 
 id="conversionService"
/>
```

While you're at it setup paging and sorting:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="conversionService">
  <mvc:argument-resolvers>
    <bean class="org.springframework.data.web.SortHandlerMethodArgumentResolver" id="sortResolver"/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.data.web.PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver" id="pagingResolver">
      <constructor-arg ref="sortResolver"/>
    </bean>
  </mvc:argument-resolvers>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

Comment: Thanks! It really helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the existing configuration from `SpringDataWebConfiguration` like this:

```
<bean id="mvcConversionService" class="org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.data.web.config.SpringDataWebConfiguration">
  <constructor-arg ref="mvcConversionService"/>
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.data.web.config.QuerydslWebConfiguration"/>

<mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="mvcConversionService">
  <mvc:argument-resolvers>
    <ref bean="sortResolver"/>
    <ref bean="pageableResolver"/>
    <ref bean="querydslPredicateArgumentResolver"/>
  </mvc:argument-resolvers>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```